# CMake FindPackage in add_subdirectory from parent dirs cmake folder

Tags: cmake

I have a CMake structure:

- `mainproject/`
- `mainproject/cmake/FindMyPackage.cmake`
- `mainproject/CMakeLists.txt`
- `plugin/`
- `plugin/CMakeLists.txt`

and in the above `CMakeLists.txt` I call

```
add_subdirectory(${LOOP_SUBDIR}/${subdir} examples/${subdir})
```

which add the `plugin/CMakeLists.txt` subdirectory outside the directory defined above.

In this second `CMakeLists.txt` I call `FindPackage(MyPackage REQUIRED)`

which give error message:

```
CMake Error at [...]/plugin/CMakeLists.txt:9 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindMyPackage.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "MyPackage", but
  CMake did not find one.
```

Is there any way to make it use the cmake files in the mainproject folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just follow given error message, i.e. this must help:

```
# CMakeLists.txt
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/mainproject/cmake")
add_subdirectory(plugin)
```